# Mutiple gridviews on same form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I would just like to know if there is a more efficient way of displaying mutiple gridviews on the same form. Lets say i have 4 gridviews displaying different data and want to display a specific one everytime i push one of 4 buttons

As of now im going this

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.DealerShipTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HermesZingoDataSet.DealerShip, ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
    dateGridView.Visible = False
    DataGridViewDealerShip.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Me.DateFilterTableAdapter.Fill(Me.dateDataSet.DateFilter, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
    DataGridViewDealerShip.Visible = False
    dateGridView.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Is there another way to code this to make all other gridviews visible = false? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do something like the following to simplify it a little bit:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ShowGridView(GridView1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ShowGridView(GridView2)
End Sub

private sub ShowGridView(gv As GridView)
  GridView1.Visible = GridView1 = gv
  GridView2.Visible = GridView2 = gv
  GridView3.Visible = GridView3 = gv
  GridView4.Visible = GridView4 = gv
End sub
```